# simple sql query with count

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, nested

I'm using SQLite.
I need an help for an easy issue.
Here's my three tables:

```
--------------
problem
--------------
id (primary key)
question_id (foreign key)

--------------
question
--------------
id (primary key)
answer_id (foreign key)

--------------
answer
--------------
id (primary key)
```

I would like to get ALL problems that have at least N answers in every question of a problem. I'll give you an example:

```
-------
problem
id 
1
2


-------
question 
id   problem_id
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2

-------
answer
id   question_id
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    4
8    4
```

If n=2, my result should be problem_id=2.

I've tried this:

```
   select distinct question.problem_id 
   from answer, question
   where answer.question_id = question.id
   group by answer.question_id
   having count(*) >= 2
```

but it doesn't work because it gets problems with at least one question with at least 2 answers. All questions must satisfy that condition.

Any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my go at the issue in T-SQL:

```
declare @problem table(id bigint not null primary key clustered)
declare @question table(id bigint not null primary key clustered, problem_id bigint)
declare @answer table(id bigint not null primary key clustered, question_id bigint)

declare @n int = 2

insert @problem
      select 1 
union select 2

insert @question
      select 1, 1 
union select 2, 1
union select 3, 1
union select 4, 2

insert @answer 
      select 1, 1 
union select 2, 1
union select 3, 1
union select 4, 2
union select 5, 2
union select 6, 3
union select 7, 4
union select 8, 4

select p.id --, p.name, p.description, p.etc
from @problem p
where @n >= ALL --http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx
(
    select COUNT(a.id) 
    from @question q
    left outer join @answer a
        on q.id = a.question_id
    where p.id = q.problem_id
    group by q.id
)
```

NB: the table schema differs slightly from the question as the schema in the question doesn't match the example data.

**ALTERNATIVE**

(based on @RichardTheKiwi's answer with the inner SQL moved to a temp table)

```
declare @tempTable table (pid bigint, qid bigint, aidCount bigint)

insert @tempTable
select q.problem_id, q.id, count(a.id) answercount
from @question q
left join @answer a on a.question_id = q.id
group by q.problem_id, q.id

select pid
from @tempTable
group by pid 
having min(aidCount) >= @n
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've copied and paste, but it seems my sqlite doesn't support "ALL" word, it generates an error

Comment: No worries - sorry it doesn't play well on SQLite; sadly I don't have a copy of that to test against.  @RichardTheKiwi's answer looks good though.  If his answer doesn't work you could try tweaking it such that you load the inner query into a temp table, the use the temp table instead of the bracketed inner query.

Comment: I think this could be the a solution.
How change the inner query?
It cannot find p.id

Comment: I split the result into a temp table and now it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
select problem_id
from
(
    select q.problem_id, q.id, count(a.id) answercount
    from question q
    left join answer a on a.question_id = q.id
    group by q.problem_id, q.id
) g
group by problem_id
having min(answercount) >= 2
```

### Alternative (for example 4 answers)

```
select distinct q.problem_id
from question q
left join answer a on a.question_id = q.id
left join answer b on b.question_id = q.id and a.id < b.id
left join answer c on c.question_id = q.id and b.id < c.id
left join answer d on d.question_id = q.id and c.id < d.id
where d.id is not null
```

You can extend this pattern as required.  If you really need to have a single query that is parameterized, you can do something crazy like join 6 times, varying the WHERE clause as follows:

```
where case when f.id is not null then 6
           when e.id is not null then 5
           when d.id is not null then 4
           when c.id is not null then 3
           when b.id is not null then 2
           else 1 end >= {{YourParamHere}}
```

Comment: It seems correct, but I've some problem with my sqlite version, so there's a bug when doing "select from (select...)". Is there another way to write that query? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't forget that. In an external software (probably with a different sqlite version) it works, but in mine doesn't and I cannot change it, so I've to write that query in another way, maybe with an INTERSECT?

Comment: I've added an alternative query

Comment: Thanks for your time. Could you explain where is the condition min(answercount) >= 2 in the alternative query? The results are different from the first one.

Comment: Maybe that's where I missed the `DISTINCT`. The fact that it can LEFT JOIN twice to get two different answers `a.id < b.id` means that there are at least two answers.

Comment: Unfortunately 2 is an arbitrary number, generally it will be a number between 0 and 6

Comment: I've edited yet again, but this is probably the last remaining idea I have

Comment: Unfortunately I can only set one right answer here in stackoverflow :/
I'll appreciate a LOT our help. Thank both of you guys, I'll put your two names in my credits' application :)

Comment: @Gore: Both? We are three, I feel neglected :)

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting as a correlated subquery. Instead of finding problems with at least N answers in every question, we find the problems where there is no question with less than N answers:

```
SELECT id AS problem_id
FROM problem AS p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM question AS q
          LEFT JOIN answer AS a 
            ON a.question_id = q.id
        WHERE q.problem_id = p.id
        GROUP BY q.id
        HAVING COUNT(a.question_id) < 2
      ) ;
```